# What does BREAK mean in real terms while using a UART?

Tags: c, arduino, uart, iar

The break and error indication glows up in real terms while communicating with RS-232.  Sometimes, the CTS is also will be glowing.

Due to this, the data in prints as junk for some time; later it gets corrected after a few reset of real term.

This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fADkj.png) showing the error:

[image: Screenshot showing error]

What does BREAK mean really?  What happens when there's a break?

Comment: In a nutshell a BREAK condition is a Frame Error. It means that parity bit and stop bits are not matched. Usually is used as start packet condition holding the line (TX) asserted for a certain time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A break condition occurs when **the transmitter is holding the data line at logical 0 for too long**, i.e. longer than the time needed for transmitting a start bit and the (usually 8) data bits. Possible causes:

The transmitter can send a break **deliberately**, as an out-of band signal, e.g. to signal the beginning of a data packet, like in the **LIN** protocol.

It can occur when the **transmitter is sending at a lower speed** as the receiver is expecting. Perhaps its clock is not properly initialized.

Of course it can be caused by a noisy or otherwise **bad connection**.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not getting you. RS232 talking to send a BREAK you must move from logical 1 (below -3V) to logical 0 (more than +3V) and hold the line there for at time that assure the receiver to trigger a frame error. The minimum time is obviously based on the current baud rate. Another matter is to see signals of UART (TTL) where all thing can be done.

Comment: @LPs I just meant that if you peek on the UART side rather than the RS232 side, then pulling data line low is the same thing as logical 0.

Comment: @Lundin Well, yes, true. I don't know if there are RS232 transceiver with inverted signals on TTL side.

Comment: @MVA It is too broad to give such a description. Frame error can be: voluntary action, a line noise problem, a mismatch of baudrate caused by thermal derating and other tons of causes.

Answer (score 2):

Valid RS-232 signals are either in the range of +3 V to +15 V for logic 0 or low and the range −3 V to −15 V for logic 1 or high with respect to the common ground.

TTL serial or UART operates at a logic 0 or low low level between 0 and 0.8 volts and a logic 1 or high level of either 5V or 3.3V, and it has a fan out of 10 gates, which means that it can support up to 10 gates. The TTL interface is a versatile, low-cost, and widely compatible one that is best regarded for its reliability and availability.

The RS-232 specification defines a break signal as when the data line remains in the space condition (Logic 0) for a specified duration, usually at least 100ms. This state is distinguishable from normal data being sent over the line and can trigger a specific action on the receiving end of the connection. A break will raise a framing error and can be used to enter SysRq mode on some Linux machines, and ROM Monitor mode on Cisco devices when a password recovery is necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).